# argument in is_member() procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In Sql Server, I have this column `NomRole` which contains names of roles which i can put security on
i tried this test to check `is_member` procedure

```
IF IS_MEMBER ('db_owner') = 1
   print 'current user is a member of the db_owner role'
else if IS_MEMBER(dbo.liaisecurité.NomRole) = 1 // <-- problem //
```

but it seems like there is a problem when i put a column instead of string in is_member() procedure
it says the multi-part indentifier "dbo.liaisecurité.NomRole" could not be bound

Answer (score 0):

First, to remove try `dbo` from under `is_member()`.

Try somethink like

```
-- Execute SELECT if user is a member of ADVWORKS\Shipping.
IF IS_MEMBER ('ADVWORKS\Shipping') = 1
   SELECT 'User ' + USER + ' is a member of ADVWORKS\Shipping.'; 
GO
```

and also if you want to pass variable value, use this sample

```
Declare @owner varchar(20)
SET @owner = 'db_owner'
SELECT IS_MEMBER(@owner)
```

Refer
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186271.aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer but i don't want to test only one variable..
i have lot of roles in my column "NomRole"